# Python, logging with asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, queue, python-asyncio, python-logging

Got stuck with logging exceptions in asyncio app.
Look at tke code below. It works, but it doesn't write anything to log file.

```
logfile='/tmp/test.log'

logger=logging.getLogger()
loghandler=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logfile, maxBytes=102400, backupCount=5)
formatter=logging.Formatter(u'%(filename)s [LINE:%(lineno)d] #%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s]  %(message)s')
loghandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logqueue = Queue()
qlistener = logging.handlers.QueueListener(logqueue, loghandler)
qhandler = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(logqueue)
logger.addHandler(qhandler)

async def go_ahead()
  a = 10/0 # raise an exception

async def main():
  try:
    await go_ahead()
  except Exception as err:
    logger.info(err, exc_info=True)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I did small research and checked log queue in main(). And it HAS a log record about an exception in go_ahead() and i can print it. So exception propogation works fine. But logger doesn't write message to file.

If i modify go_ahead() in this way, everything works fine

```
async def go_ahead()
  try:
    a = 10/0 # raise an exception
  except Exception as err:
    logger.info(err, exc_info=True)
```

Please help me to fix it.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the `qlistener`:

```py
import asyncio
import logging
from multiprocessing import Queue

logfile = "log.txt"

logger = logging.getLogger()

loghandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    logfile, maxBytes=102400, backupCount=5
)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    "%(filename)s [LINE:%(lineno)d] #%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s]  %(message)s"
)
loghandler.setFormatter(formatter)

logqueue = Queue()
qhandler = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(logqueue)
logger.addHandler(qhandler)

qlistener = logging.handlers.QueueListener(logqueue, loghandler)

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
qlistener.start()


async def go_ahead():
    a = 10 / 0  # raise an exception


async def main():
    try:
        await go_ahead()
    except Exception as err:
        logger.info(err, exc_info=True)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Running it the `log.txt` will contain:

```
script.py [LINE:159] #INFO     [2023-10-27 19:15:49,726]  division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/app/script.py", line 156, in main
    await go_ahead()
  File "/root/app/script.py", line 151, in go_ahead
    a = 10 / 0  # raise an exception
        ~~~^~~
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: It doesn't wotk for me. log.txt is emty.

Comment: @RamessesIII Try to copy-paste the script as I have exactly. You should see the exception in the file. Then modify the real code.

Comment: Copy-paste gave me an eror "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File /log.py", line 10, in <module>
    loghandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'handlers'. Did you mean: '_handlers'?

Comment: @RamessesIII What version of Python are you using? I'm on 3.11

Comment: I'm on 3.10.9 and it doesn work even if i add `from logging import handlers`

Comment: @RamessesIII https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.handlers.html#module-logging.handlers is standard python module